# Libcurl windows build VS2015 OpenSSL HTTP2

Tags: c++, curl, openssl, libcurl, nghttp2

I am currently trying to build Libcurl 7.54.0 with OpenSSL and HTTP2 on windows 10 using Visual Studio 2015 and I am getting these errors in the build log at the end of compilation:

```
1>libcurl.lib(http2.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__nghttp2_session_callbacks_new referenced in function _Curl_http2_init
1>libcurl.lib(http2.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__nghttp2_session_callbacks_del referenced in function _Curl_http2_init
1>libcurl.lib(http2.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__nghttp2_session_callbacks_set_send_callback referenced in function _Curl_http2_init
1>libcurl.lib(http2.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__nghttp2_session_callbacks_set_on_frame_recv_callback referenced in function _Curl_http2_init
1>libcurl.lib(http2.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__nghttp2_session_callbacks_set_on_invalid_frame_recv_callback referenced in function _Curl_http2_init
1>libcurl.lib(http2.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__nghttp2_session_callbacks_set_on_data_chunk_recv_callback referenced in function _Curl_http2_init
1>libcurl.lib(http2.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__nghttp2_session_callbacks_set_before_frame_send_callback referenced in function _Curl_http2_init
1>libcurl.lib(http2.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__nghttp2_session_callbacks_set_on_frame_send_callback referenced in function _Curl_http2_init
1>libcurl.lib(http2.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__nghttp2_session_callbacks_set_on_frame_not_send_callback referenced in function _Curl_http2_init
1>libcurl.lib(http2.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__nghttp2_session_callbacks_set_on_stream_close_callback referenced in function _Curl_http2_init
1>libcurl.lib(http2.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__nghttp2_session_callbacks_set_on_begin_headers_callback referenced in function _Curl_http2_init
1>libcurl.lib(http2.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__nghttp2_session_callbacks_set_on_header_callback referenced in function _Curl_http2_init
1>libcurl.lib(http2.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__nghttp2_session_callbacks_set_error_callback referenced in function _Curl_http2_init
1>libcurl.lib(http2.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__nghttp2_session_client_new referenced in function _Curl_http2_init
1>libcurl.lib(http2.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__nghttp2_session_del referenced in function _http2_disconnect
1>libcurl.lib(http2.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__nghttp2_session_send referenced in function _h2_session_send
1>libcurl.lib(http2.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__nghttp2_session_mem_recv referenced in function _Curl_http2_switched
1>libcurl.lib(http2.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__nghttp2_session_resume_data referenced in function _Curl_http2_done_sending
1>libcurl.lib(http2.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__nghttp2_session_want_read referenced in function _should_close_session
1>libcurl.lib(http2.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__nghttp2_session_want_write referenced in function _http2_perform_getsock
1>libcurl.lib(http2.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__nghttp2_session_get_stream_user_data referenced in function _before_frame_send
1>libcurl.lib(http2.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__nghttp2_session_set_stream_user_data referenced in function _Curl_http2_done
1>libcurl.lib(http2.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__nghttp2_session_get_remote_settings referenced in function _on_frame_recv
1>libcurl.lib(http2.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__nghttp2_session_upgrade referenced in function _Curl_http2_switched
1>libcurl.lib(http2.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__nghttp2_pack_settings_payload referenced in function _Curl_http2_request_upgrade
1>libcurl.lib(http2.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__nghttp2_strerror referenced in function _Curl_http2_switched
1>libcurl.lib(http2.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__nghttp2_http2_strerror referenced in function _Curl_http2_strerror
1>libcurl.lib(http2.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__nghttp2_priority_spec_init referenced in function _h2_pri_spec
1>libcurl.lib(http2.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__nghttp2_submit_request referenced in function _http2_send
1>libcurl.lib(http2.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__nghttp2_submit_priority referenced in function _h2_session_send
1>libcurl.lib(http2.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__nghttp2_submit_rst_stream referenced in function _Curl_http2_done
1>libcurl.lib(http2.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__nghttp2_submit_settings referenced in function _Curl_http2_switched
1>libcurl.lib(http2.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__nghttp2_session_set_local_window_size referenced in function _Curl_http2_switched
1>libcurl.lib(http2.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__nghttp2_version referenced in function _Curl_http2_ver
1>libcurl.lib(http2.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__nghttp2_is_fatal referenced in function _Curl_http2_switched
1>..\..\..\..\build\Win32\VC14\LIB Release - DLL OpenSSL\curl.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 35 unresolved externals
```

According to OpenSSL & nghttp2 path on my computer, I have added the following to curl & libcurl project:
I have added the following folders to my additionnal library directories (curl project->properties->configuration properties->linker->general->additionnal library directories) :

```
C:\OpenSSL-Win32\lib
C:\nghttp2-1.22.0\lib
```

And added for both curl and libcurl project additionnal include directories (both projects->properties->configuration properties->c/c++->general->additionnal include directories) :

```
C:\OpenSSL-Win32\include
C:\nghttp2-1.22.0\lib\includes
```

I also added the definition of USE_NGHTTP2 to both project preprocessor definitions (both projects->properties->configuration properties->C/C++->Preprocessor->Preprocessor Definitions) in order to compile with nghttp2.

Finally, I am building using configuration "LIB Release - DLL OpenSSL" with target platform Win32.

Edit: the issue seems to be related to nghttp2 as I successfully build without the NGHTTP2 preprocessor definition.

I am surely missing something but I can't see what at the moment.

Thank you for your assistance

Lucas

Comment: Where did you specify the names of the libraries to use in the build?  Path names are not enough -- you have to tell Visual Studio (either as a linker option, or as a `#pragma lib` in the source code) the names of the libraries to link to.

Comment: I guess I missed that part, how can I do that ?

PS: the issue comes from building with nghttp2 as I successfully build without the USE_NGHTTP2 preprocessor definition.

Comment: In your project settings for "Linker -> Input", what are the "Additional Dependencies"?  That is where you would add the name of the third-party .lib file to the dependencies.  All the path setting does is tell which directory to search for those items you specified in the "Additional Dependencies" section.

Comment: Oh, right, problem solved. Thank you for your help

Comment: Please show your compile and link commands.